# Start standalone full-screen google chrome apps by command line

Tags: command-line, x11, chrome

I can run google-chrome app standalone this way:

```
google-chrome --app="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#main_7"
```

but cannot open calendar in maximized window. A script is running without error but without any change in size:

```
#!/bin/bash
`which google-chrome` --app="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render" --geometry=2000x1000
```

---

**why '--geometry':**

chrome is GTK+ application, and its man page mention that:

> As a GTK+ app, Google Chrome also obeys GTK+ command-line flags, such as --display.  See the GTK documentation for more:
>
> library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-running.html
> library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-x11.html

But I found this page more helpful:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/cli.html and assume that geometry flag is also available in chrome:

> [--geometry=GEOMETRY]